# Adding this.id to JS array

Tags: jquery, .net

I am trying to add id of an element to an array. But I am getting the error - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method.
Below image shows how I am adding the id value to array. Also why is value of $(this).id undefined?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be doing:

```
var comments = [];
//instead of
var comments = {};
```

**So it would be:**

```
var comments = [];
$("textarea.comment_wide_textbox_control").each(function() {
    comments.push($(this).attr("id"), $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try `$(this).attr('id');`

Comment: `this.id` works just fine.  No need to use jQuery where it adds no value and solves no problem.